# How does Laravel Views Cache works?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, view, laravel-blade

According to Laravel's documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#introduction) views are compiled into plain PHP code and cached until they are modified but when are they re-compiled?

I have my project in a production environment and when I deploy changes are automatically showed, I don't need to clear views cache or something similar.

Are views re-compiled automatically (in that case, when does it happen?) or do I haven't cache enabled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default all views are `compiled/cached`. You can define a path where to store compiled version in `app/config/view.php`. When Laravel framework tries to compile a view it check the modification date of the source view file and compiled version if the last one exists. If the compiled file is older than a the source file Laravel recompiled the view and store it as a new cached version of the source file. It happens every time when you deploy a new version of the code.

Comment: do you know where exactly (file and line) this date comparison is made?

Comment: I guess here \Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler::isExpired @Alan

Comment: After caching the view files... the view resources are no longer of use (in production)?

Comment: do you know when the method \Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler::isExpired call?