# define a new way to use php tag and code in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

**hello**,

i want to know how a framework like laravel change

```
<?php echo ?>
```

to this

```
{{ }}
```

?
i have a few ideas to use json and javascript but i can't really understant it. 
maybe even using functions and define to make codes like "echo" smaller but php tag is something else, overall i want to know what is the best way to do this ? to change php tag and code to what i want and make html undrstand it ?
sorry if my question is duplicated or else but it's making me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel (and others like Twig) use a interpreter/compiler to transform their meta-language into PHP. You can find [Laravel's compilers here](https://github.com/illuminate/view/tree/master/Compilers) and even some more specified compilers that [translate into PHP code here](https://github.com/illuminate/view/blob/master/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesConditionals.php). The compiled PHP is usually/always [cached somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39210117/231316) for performance reasons.